# Rewrite URL to canonical?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to rewrite or redirect if you access a page and the URL doesn't match the canonical link to the correct canonical link?

If so how would I go about this? I assume it is going to be something along the lines of get the url, compare it to canonical, if it doesn't match then rewrite/redirect to correct URL in canonical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here.

http://www.seo-consultant-services.co.uk/301-redirects-www-non-www-canonical-problems.html

Answer (score -1):

Something along the lines of:

```
$canonical_link="whatever";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]!=$canonical_link)
{
     header("Location: $canonical_link");
}
```

Comment: One of the tags (in fact, the first one) on the question was "php". I think it depends how dynamic the URLs are - if it's for a set of 10 static pages then .htaccess is probably the way to go but if it's for a CMS or something I reckon PHP/ASP (whatever you're using) is the place to do it. In this case, the original question was in the context of PHP.